# Locate specific folders

Tags: locate

I want to locate all folders on my server that end with 'wordpress-seo'.

I tried **find** command but it takes too long.

```
sudo  find /home/w/s -type d -name 'wordpress-seo'
```

Now I am trying `locate` command but it returns all paths that have wordpress-seo.

```
a/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo
a/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/languages/
...
...
```

I want to exclude `wordpress-seo/*` files and folders. I just want folder names. i.e.

```
a/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo
b/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo
```

Tried regex without any luck.

```
locate -r '/\w+wordpress\-seo/b'
OR
locate '/*/wordpress-seo/'
```

Any Help??

Comment: I'm surprised 'find' is too slow. This is just the sort of job it is good at. Can you limit the depth of the search with -maxdepth?

Comment: what filesystem? btrfs? can you be sure that `locate` will work? Seems to me it reads from a system database of system files and not from the real directories...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
locate -r "wordpress-seo$"
```

Although i should mention that `find` offers huge variations of options over `locate`. You have found `locate` faster because it just reads from a database `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db` while `find` search through files every time, whenever you give it something to search.

`locate`'s database is updated by `cron` on a daily basis, you can also update the database manually anytime by:

```
sudo updatedb
```

This will make the files created after the daily `cron` update available in the `locate` database, so you will find those via `locate`. Also check the configuration file `/etc/updatedb` to see which filesystems, paths are being excluded.

Comment: Thanks man.. it worked for me. Will accept in 6 minutes/

Comment: NOTE: You should check the /etc/updatedb.conf to ensure it is catching all the areas that you are interested in.  Also, remember that the locate output is only at the point when updatedb was done, whereas find uses what is on the disk NOW.

Comment: @mdpc: Thanks..added the conf file info too..

Comment: I like how you mentioned that `locate` reads from a database. `locate` isn't magically faster than `find`. It does come at a cost albeit one that isn't too high anymore.

Comment: Basically you are substituting a limited find done during an early morning most likely taking the time (cpu, io, wait) rather than doing it NOW and waiting then.  Tradeoff is the accuracy of the list ... it might be older than you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Always better late than never. `fd` is the new find.

### Options:

- `H` - search hidden files and folders
- `I` - do not respect ignore files
- `t` - type of file to search for (d == directory)

### Usage:

```bsh
fd -HI -t d 'wordpress-seo$'
```

As for speed, you can find [benchmarks here](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#benchmark), but strictly speaking `fd` is exponentially faster than `find`.

#### Fedora Install:

```bsh
sudo dnf install fd-find
```

#### Debian Install:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install fd-find
```

Other installation methods can be found at the [github](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#installation)